# Clob or Blob support for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, blob, clob

1. Does Neo4j support Clob or Blob datatype? 
   I reviewed  the documentation, but found that Neo4j supports only primitive datatypes as properties of Nodes or relationships.
2. Do we have any restriction to number of properties, can Node or relationship hold? What is the optimal size for that?

Comment: 2. there is no restriction to the number of properties per node or rel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find [this link informative](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/manual/src/qanda/index.asciidoc), it addresses many scalability issues.

A key quote, that gets to your question:

> Neo4j is currently not suitable for storing BLOBs/CLOBs. Nodes,
>   relationships, and properties are not co-located on disk. This might
>   be introduced in the future.

Now, you can use [`setProperty`](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) on a node to store a `byte[]` or a `String`, so in this sense you can store arbitrary binary objects or Strings.

But storing very large objects like that above a certain size probably wouldn't be a very good idea.   What's that size threshold?   Unfortunately I don't know.  Someone else  may jump in with some advice or guidance there.   Presumably, at some point performance may begin to degrade in some way, and of course just to set the property, the object in question would have to fit into memory.

Comment: Usually you put your binary objects into blob storage like s3, a filesystem or a key-value-store and just store the URI in Neo4j.

Comment: @MichaelHunger for BLOBs that sounds like a reasonable solution.  For CLOBs, sometimes it's desirable to be able to search them, and it might be nice (eventually) to be able to use lucene indexing with those.  Then again that might blur the lines, and neo4j isn't supposed to really be a document repo.  :)